# Read traffic light from Router to simulate lights on python/shell script

Tags: python, networking, router, modem

I want To Read my Internet router traffic light(Power + adsl ) light to simulate the real time Lights as my modem is located far from my room and my dsl lights keeps disconnecting frequently , So it becomes a pain to check it status every time lights go out...
How Can I Do this in python (I have Read about pyserial But not getting a way to do it ..)?
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

A very common way of monitoring router status is by using snmp.
As a summary, for a small home router, it involves at least the following steps:

1. Enable snmp in your router (this usually is only setup "snmp
   communities", they are the passwords for reading and writing). If
   your router allows it, I recommend to you to add an IP filter as
   well for filtering from what IP addresses snmp queries are allowed.
2. Read SNMP OIDs (for instance, interface status list, interface usage
   stats, etc), you can use snmpwalk for testing.
3. Once you can read standard values with snmpwalk you can load your
   router MIB file into your local MIB files repo (that enables you to
   read specific attributes from your router manufacturer).
4. Setup your monitoring software (nagios is a very popular one). As
   you said you will use python, I believe you can use pysnmp.